# Can I get image info (resolution, etc) inside of Nautilus on mouse over or single click?

Tags: gnome, 11.10, nautilus, 11.04, metadata

I use Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome 3 (gnome shell) UI.

Is it possible to get a quick image info by clicking or hovering the image, without having to right click > **Properties > Image**?

I often have to know image resolution and repeating these steps for 100 images is so frustrating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 11.04 and earlier, the package [nautilus-columns](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/music-and-exif-metadata-information-in.html) package can be added to integrate the feature into nautilus so a resolution column can be added, like this:

[image: http://lh5.ggpht.com/_1QSDkzYY2vc/TMv7I1oSSDI/AAAAAAAACM8/Uh5hCMuXNBs/s2000/nautilus-music-columns.png]

Unfortunately no one has updated it for Gnome 3.x, so it won't work on 11.10 and later. On these versions of Ubuntu, I prefer to use the app [gThumb](http://live.gnome.org/gthumb/screenshots) rather than fight with the limited feature set of nautilus. GThumb is in the Ubuntu repositories.

[image: Gthumb]